# Store data on WP7?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to store a few KB of data on a windows phone. I am using phonegap and jquery mobile.

So far I worked with [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info) and that worked well on iOS and Android. jStorage tries localStorage, globalStorage and userData behavior. I also tried cookies.

But nothing worked. Any solution to this? Maybe using `PhoneGap.exec`, again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Open Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Source: [docs.phonegap.com](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Comment: I don't understand how this can work. According to the documentation (and my testing), this is unsupported on wp7 as of PhoneGap/Cordova 2.8.0

Answer (score 3):

I store & read some small amount of data using phonegap & jQm & wp7

Store some data:

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
```

Read some data:

```
JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key))
```

Check if you are using the newest jquery.mobile.js from [jQm beta page](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/) - there was a new release yesterday